# quick-swap TUI mode while using vi keybindings in GDB

Tags: debugging, vi, readline, gdb

In the default mode of `gdb`, pressing `ctrl+x a` turns on and off the UI, and `ctrl+x 2` cycles through different split views.  There are a number of similar useful shortcuts.

I can turn on `vi` emulation either with `esc ctrl+j`, or by adding `set editing-mode vi` into `~/.inputrc`.

When `vi` emulation is enabled, `ctrl+x` now puts the characters `^X` into my prompt, and the shortcuts cease to function. How do I fix this?

Cheers

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Vim. Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and found the needed required incantation buried in the [GDB info pages](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-emacs_002dediting_002dmode-_0028C_002de_0029):

> `emacs-editing-mode (C-e)`
>
> When in `vi` command mode,
> this causes a switch to `emacs` editing mode.

So if you are in vi-mode, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> (to get out of vi insert mode) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to get back to Emacs mode.

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> should work as expected as the leader escape for the TUI.